# Rails polymorphic has_one build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations, has-one-through

Given a `ContentBlock` model:

```
class ContentBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :block_association
  has_one :image, through: :block_association, source: :content, source_type: "Image"
  has_one :snippet, through: :block_association, source: :content, source_type: "Snippet"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :snippet, allow_destroy: true
end
```

BlockAssociation model:

```
class BlockAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content_block
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
end
```

Snippet model:

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :block_association, as: :content
  has_one :content_block, through: :block_association

  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

I need to do:

`@content_block.build_snippet`

but this gives:

`undefined method 'build_snippet' for #<ContentBlock:0x007ffb7edde330>`

How would I achieve the intended result?

The form would be something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @content_block do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for f.object.snippet || f.object.build_snippet do |sf| %>
    <%= sf.input :body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(Originally I had assumed that `content_block` would simply `belong_to :content, polymorphic: true` but that seemed inadequate due to the multiple `content` types.)

This is kind of close to what I'm doing, but I just can't quite get my head around it: http://xtargets.com/2012/04/04/solving-polymorphic-hasone-through-building-and-nested-forms/

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You want to have a content_block which has one snippet and one image. You want to refer to the associated snippet and image as content.
I don't think you can make "build_snippet" to work at all, but it is possible to do something like "@content_block.content = Snippet.create(...)"

Answer (score 0):

```
class ContentBlock < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_one :snippet, through: :block_association, source: :content, source_type: "Snippet"
end
```

This tells rails, you want instances of ContentBlock (lets make content_block this instance) to have one instance of Snippet called "snippet" of the fake-type "content" through BlockAssociation. ContentBlock instances should hence be able to respond to content_block.content which would retourn a collection of a snippet and/or image (I left out the image part in the code-snippets). How content_block can call only snippet content no one knows yet.

What does your BlockAssociation Model know:

```
class BlockAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content_block
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
end
```

It knows it belongs to a content_block and knows (since it will respond to content) one or more contents which have a content_type ('Snippet') and a content_id (1 or whatever snippets id is), the combination of those makes the relation to snippet

Now what you were missing was the Snippet part:

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :block_association, :as => :snippet_content
  has_one :content_block, :through => :content_association # I'm actually not quite sure of this
end
```

Which tells block_association how to call this type of content, since you want to differ between image-content and snippet-content. Now content_block.snippet_content should return the snippet and snippet.block_content should return block_content.

I hope I didn't mess anything up, these relations allways get my head spinning

Comment: `snippet_content` is not defined as a relationship in the `content_block` model, so calling `block_block.snippet_content` won't work here